# question about the nodehandle for subscribing and publishing

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, nodehandle, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have created my own package (with catkin) in which I am subscribing and publishing to several topics. So far, for each topic (wheather for subcribing or publishing) I have created a seperate nodehandle and I was wondering if that is actually necessary or if something like this (basically just having one single nodehandle) is possible:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_my_pkg("~");     
ros::Publisher publisher = nh_my_pkg.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/topic name", 1);
ros::Subscriber subscriber = nh_my_pkg.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/topic name", 1, &my_class::callback_fct, this);
```

Thanks and have a nice day

Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197066/question-about-the-nodehandle-for-subscribing-and-publishing/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, reusing your `NodeHandle` instance is perfectly fine in general.

In your specific example though, you are creating a `NodeHandle` referencing the *private* namespace ("~") of the node, then start creating publishers and subscribers through it that publish and subscribe to topics that appear to be in the *global* namespace. I'm not sure, but that either won't work, or the node will try to find `/topic_name` in its private namespace, and fail.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-11-10**:
Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify tho, you would suggest to use:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_my_pkg;
```

instead of:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_my_pkg("~");
```

correct?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-10**:
No: `NodeHandle`s for parameters usually access a node's private namespace ("~"). Topics are normally in the global / relative namespace, so you'd need a second `NodeHandle` instance for that. The second one can then be re-used by your publishers / subscribers.